# How to render a React component with Python Tornado template?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, tornado, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to modify login page UI (with **React**) in **JupyterLab**, it seems like its server consists of Python **Tornado** and renders `login.html` as one of templates. (literally stored in templates directory. `...jupyter_server\templates\`) It might also render others like `404.html`, `error.html` respectively in terms of contexts.

I simply followed https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html like below so:

page.html

```
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>{% block title %}Jupyter Server{% endblock %}</title>
                                           :
                                           :
                                          
    <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
    <div id="like_button_container"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    {% block login %}  
    {% endblock login %}
  
</body>

</html>
```

logint.html

```
{% extends "page.html" %}

{% block login %}
    <script src="like_button.js"></script>
    <script>console.log('This is Login page.')</srcipt> // logs shows fine
    <h1>This is Login Page.</h1> // tag shows fine  
{% endblock login %}
```

As I understand so far, when the url hit as login, `login.html` renders with appending its contents to `page.html`.

I was expecting the `like_button.js` component renders fine but it is the only thing excluded. The log and `h1` are visible correctly meanwhile.

Have I missed something? any ideas welcome.

Comment: Where is this `like_button.js` file located? You need to use the appropriate src. If it's in a folder called `static`, you can try `src="{{ static_url('like_button.js') }}"`.

Comment: @xyres I just set the src path without any curly braces(just like normal html) and this is why it did not work. You save my day thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer. Mark it as "accepted answer" to make the question solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` of the script isn't correct. In Tornado, you put your static files in a folder called `static` and then set the `src` like this:

```
<script src="{{ static_url('like_button.js')"></script>
```

If you put the file in a subfolder such as `static/js/`, then provide its relative path:

```
<script src="{{ static('js/like_button.js') }}"></script>
```